# Unexpected result in php strtotime() when using a space after 'T'

Tags: php, datetime-format, strtotime

I've noticed a strange behaviour of strtotime() function when inserting a space after 'T' in a Date/time string (using PHP 7.1 on Debian).

I'm getting:

```
strtotime('1970-01-01 00:00:00Z') = 0 //as expected
strtotime('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z') = 0 //as expected
strtotime('1970-01-01 T 00:00:00Z') = 25200 //7 hours more...

strtotime('1970-01-01T00:00:00-12:00') = 43200 //as expected
strtotime('1970-01-01 T 00:00:00-12:00') = 25200 //Same as before...
```

Affected lines don't strictly respect (because of spaces) the format reported in http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php, and a fast solution is to get rid of all spaces in time strings, but I'm surprised about the behaviour of the functions: where does the 7 hours (25200 seconds) come from?

Comment: Smells like it comes from your local timezone.

Comment: Are you perchance located in the timezone +7?

Comment: It probably stops parsing the string when it diverges from the standard format and substitutes local time(-zone).

Comment: The moral being that `strtotime` isn't magic and won't parse anything and everything you throw at it How You Meant It™, so you better stick to the supported formats.

Comment: [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (which has the `T`) does not use spaces. PHP isn't recognizing the format

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams
No, my time zone is +01:00, already considered that

Comment: @TomRegner, no, mine is +01:00